# plotting issue on R (using heatmaps)

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I have a matrix to plot and I am using the following lines:

```
library(lattice)
levelplot(cont.freq)
```

I want to get rid of the black things in the plot? I would like to use rownames and colnames of the matrix for x&y labeling. However I don't know how to represent them in a nice way.

By the way, matrix is 1284x1284..

[image]

Comment: Can you show sample of cont.freq and your whole code?

Comment: for example:
    a=rep(0:1,5)
    b=rep(0,10)
    c=rep(1,10)
    cont.freq=matrix(cbind(a,b,c),nrow=10,ncol=10)
    cont.freq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following works:

```
x_at <- pretty(seq_len(nrow(cont.freq)))
y_at <- pretty(seq_len(ncol(cont.freq)))
levelplot(cont.freq, rm.na = TRUE, scales=list(y=list(at=y_at),x=list(at=x_at)), xlab="Residue ID", ylab="Residue ID", main="Contact Frequency")
```